# Adding an overload to the setState function when that passes to the child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to pass `setState` to the child, but I need to overload more actions when `setState` called.

I was able to do it,

But I could not accept the behavior of `setState` to can get prev State as normal `setState` work.

Example:

Parent function

```
function Parent (){
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

    const $setIsOpen = (isOpen) => {
    //do somthing 
    setIsOpen(isOpen)
   }

   Child(isOpen ,$setIsOpen)
}
```

Child function

```
function Child (isOpen, setIsOpen){
  
   setIsOpen(true) //this work

   setIsOpen((prevState) => (!prevState))//but this doesn't work

}
```

How can do that as well?

If you could give me an example in TypeScript, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case for typescript you should use the proper type, since is a boolean will be this: `React.SetStateAction<boolean>`. This can receive the value in the same way the `setState` function does.

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

const $setIsOpen = (value: React.SetStateAction<boolean>) => {
    //do something...
    setIsOpen(value)
}
```

Now for the `Child` component add the proper types to the props.

```
interface IChildProps {
    isOpen: boolean
    setIsOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
}

const Child: React.FC<IChildProps> = ({ isOpen, setIsOpen }) => {
    setIsOpen(true) //this work
    setIsOpen((prevState) => (!prevState))// Now this works
    return (<></>)
}
```

Just take into account that the value passed to the `$setIsOpen` now could be a function, need to check inside if you are gonna have some logic that relies in the value.

*Note: I Defined the functions as components but for normal functions will be the same typing.*

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/zen-snyder-yihc65?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: you only added a type on paren but that really does not work

Comment: @Yoel I tested and it works, which part doesnt work for you?

Comment: setIsOpen in child doesn't work in second example

Comment: I created this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/zen-snyder-yihc65?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark , it seems to work on both function and boolean type, or is anything I missunderstood on your question description?

Comment: you right
its work
please add your sandbox into your answer